# Execute next / previous migration with doctrine migrations using symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3, doctrine-migrations

I know that I can run specific migrations using `execute` with `up` / `down` and version number, ie

`doctrine:migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --down`

My question then - is there an easier way to simply run the next or previous migration without having to look up version numbers?

Ideally I would like something like

`doctrine:migrations:execute --down n`

Where `n` is the number of migrations to run from current in the specified direction.

(same idea as `rake db:rollback STEP=n`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Closest thing to what I was looking for is:

`doctrine:migrations:migrate prev`

`doctrine:migrations:migrate next`

These cannot be used in conjunction with `n` though, so if you want to do more than 1 you need to use `doctrine:migrations:migrate` with the version number you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

i usually just call `status`, which shows if there any new ones. If so then I call `migrate`, and it runs all the new ones. See Docs here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html